# Chrome localhost does not work

Tags: google-chrome, dns, localhost

I have defined some virtual servers that until the last days were working fine.

Now they don't on Chrome, but there are no problems in firefox or safary.

I get this:

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION
>
> Hide details
>
> This site is using a new generic top-level domain (gTLD). If you have
>   used loc.dev to access an internal site in the past, contact your
>   network administrator.

I found as a solution:

Set the "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled" in chrome://flags, but the is no such flag in my chrome version ( 43.0.2357.81 )

Do you know a solution for this?

LE : If i move the site on the htdocs file and i go on the url http://localhost, it works. It seems that it has a problem only with virtualhosts.

Answer (score 19):

Got the same issue after updating to the latest chrome version last night. I was getting a  ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error only on google chrome for all of my virtual hosts. Here's how that looked.

Screen Shot-> DNS name not resolved error [image: DNS name not resolved error]

Here's the fix I made.

Clear up the google DNS cache by typing this in the Chrome browser

- **chrome://net-internals/#dns**

Screenshot -> Flushing Chrome DNS cache [image: Flushing Chrome DNS cache]

- You will see a button "Clear Host Cache". Press that DNS cache
  will be flushed.
- Keep this DNS window open. Now access the virtual host in the browser
  for me it was http:/api.localhost. Once you do that you will see a
  new    entry in the DNS window. for me it was "**localhost.**" 
  notice the period "**.**" at the end of localhost that showed an error.
- Last step is to simply add this entry as to your localhost file.

Your hosts file should be updated with an entry to resolve **localhost.** to 127.0.0.1:

```
# dont forget the trailing . !!!
127.0.0.1 localhost.
```

in the hosts file located at:

- for linux   : **/etc/hosts**
- for windows : **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

Another solution for your case might be to ditch the .dev at the end of your local virtual host domain

This has to do with some new changes by google. ".dev" comes under google's TLD (In the corner of the internet where people care about DNS, there is a bit of an uproar at Google's application for over a hundred new top-level domains, including .dev)

Try this Use a domain name you own. Possibly using the full name like "localhost.dev.$yourdomain" could help you here depending on your setup.

Comment: @user3429655. Thanks for your reply

I tried this.Here what i still get:

loc.dev IPV4 error: -166 (ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION) 2015-05-27 11:07:05.272 [Expired]

My virtualhost:


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/work/claudiu/loc/site"
ServerName loc.dev
ServerAlias www.loc.dev
<Directory "D:/work/claudiu/loc/site">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

My hosts file :

127.0.0.1 localhost.
127.0.0.1 loc.dev.

I restrated the xampp server.

Comment: whats the host name at the DNS flush screen -> chrome://net-internals/#dns

when you access the virtual host link after flushing it 

www.loc.dev

Comment: www.loc.dev IPV4 error: -166 (ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION) 2015-05-27 11:12:23.619 [Expired]

Comment: okay then add this in your hosts file

127.0.0.1   www.loc.dev

Comment: It has the same result.

Comment: I think its a different issue please reffer to this if it helps -> http://superuser.com/questions/919278/err-icann-name-collision-when-trying-to-use-localhost-dev-in-chrome

Comment: @Twrech : i tried with several names, but on chrome i got the same result. However, they don;t work on any other browsers (loc.localserver, loc.localdomain, loc.local)

Comment: if the new domains  are not working on other browsers there might be a Apache config issue. I suggest you make the new Server name work with any of the other browsers and then test on chrome. I am pretty sure its the TLD issue with ".dev" in your local domain that's conflicting with chrome. Check the addition to my answer. also check this news item -> http://tech.slashdot.org/story/15/02/28/1333231/google-taking-over-new-tlds

Comment: @Twrech do you have any ideea what could cause this problem?

Comment: as mentioned in my last comment -> Another solution for your case might be to ditch the .dev at the end of your local virtual host domain

This has to do with some new changes by google. ".dev" comes under google's TLD (In the corner of the internet where people care about DNS, there is a bit of an uproar at Google's application for over a hundred new top-level domains, including .dev)

Try this Use a domain name you own. Possibly using the full name like "localhost.dev.$yourdomain" could help you here depending on your setup.

Comment: @wiktus239  awesome ;)

Comment: Another solution for your case might be to ditch the .dev at the end of your local virtual host domain
I confirm the following:
This has to do with some new changes by google. ".dev" comes under google's TLD (In the corner of the internet where people care about DNS, there is a bit of an uproar at Google's application for over a hundred new top-level domains, including .dev)

Comment: I confirm the following solution already proposed by Pranav Singh:

"
Another solution for your case might be to ditch the .dev at the end of your local virtual host domain

This has to do with some new changes by google. ".dev" comes under google's TLD (In the corner of the internet where people care about DNS, there is a bit of an uproar at Google's application for over a hundred new top-level domains, including .dev)
"

Try using    .local   .mydev    .lan    etc

Answer (score 3):

With the 'chrome' I face the same issue because by mistake I comment out the 
127.0.0.1 localhost from the host file, But 'Firefox' will work.

```
Just make sure your host file include 
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:
chrome://net-internals/#hsts -> Domain Security Policy -> Delete domain security policies -> enter there *localhost* and press *delete*

Answer (score 0):

Here is another catch for you, my virtual hosts in Windows hosts file were defined as:

```
127.0.0.1 bla.bla.bla.localhost
127.0.0.1 bla2.bla2.localhost
```

And actual server virtual host directives in Xamp Apache Vhosts file made it all work nicely in all browsers, but Chrome!

A simple fix - dont end with full "locahost" word, rename the vhosts to end with anything else, just "loc" did it in my case, all works in Chrome now!

Answer (score 0):

**FIXING**
Try contacting your system administrator.
`ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION`.

if you are using `magento` and getting such error

- just go to you database and search for `core_config_data`
- click on it then check your web store name
- change the store name
- restart your wamp and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Been having this problem with Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) of chrome, attempting to access a vm by gset.localhost, just would not work.

Changed the url in the hosts file to gset.loc and it works fine.

The answer seems to be do not use localhost in your hosts file urls when attempting to access a virtual machine running on your machine using chrome.

Comment: Some sample lines of your hosts file would be fine for OP to understand better.

Answer (score -2):

All browsers - chrome, firefox, safari were not resolving my virtual host and kept re-directing to www.mysite.dev
After pulling my hair for hours - it turned out I just need to change mysite.dev to www.mysite.dev in the /etc/hosts file.