# Can't use subdomain in Chrome using Apache (XAMPP)

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, xampp

I'm using a couple subdomains for a project that I'm working on, but it doesn't want to render the page locally and gives this error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION
```

I thought this might be related to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467573/chrome-localhost-does-not-work), but making a change from .dev to .local (or the other suggestion) doesn't solve the issue, and it still provides the above error no matter the extension.  I'm also able to use my project.dev domain with no issues and all my other projects with .dev extensions work.  These subdomains used to work, but now about 3 months later now that development is continuing they are no longer working, anyone have any ideas what the issue might be?

vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Host that will serve this project
    ServerName project.dev
    ServerAlias project.dev

    # The location of our projects public directory
    DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/project/app/webroot"

    # Useful logs for debug
    ErrorLog "logs/project.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project-access.log" common

    # Rewrites for pretty URLs, better not to rely on .htaccess
    <Directory "D:/htdocs/project/">
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Host that will serve this project
    ServerName sales.project.dev
    ServerAlias sales.project.dev

    # The location of our projects public directory
    DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/project/app/webroot"

    # Useful logs for debug
    ErrorLog "logs/project.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project-access.log" common

    # Rewrites for pretty URLs, better not to rely on .htaccess
    <Directory "D:/htdocs/project/">
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1           project.dev
```

Comment: I take it you've restarted your apache? Also, [this](http://superuser.com/q/919278) might be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Darren.  Yah I restarted Apache.  This is essentially the same solution from above, but I don't understand why project.dev works, but subdomain.project.dev doesn't.  Shouldn't they both be broken then?

Comment: What happens if you add `127.0.0.1           sales.project.dev` into your hosts?

Comment: Hi @Darren I didn't even consider that since this was working before and I've setup local subdomains this way in the past, but that definitely works.  Thanks

Comment: I've done the same as you've tried before, maybe you threw in a wildcard domain! So it works by specifying it directly?

Comment: This subject interests me. I've started to change all of my custom virtual host domains to .loc as I have read .local can cause problems on Mac and I use a PC and a Mac. Everything seems to work. Also,  on Chrome I get the Icann error for .dev, on Firefox you don't, but on Firefox developer it just continues to "search" and never connects. So, I can see how this can be confusing to many people.