# Chrome and Opera not using virtual host

Tags: apache, google-chrome, virtualhost, opera

I have a Win7 64bit machine for development with apache2.

I have some virtualhosts like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin v.......@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/Apache/htdocs/test/"
    ServerName test.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/test.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin v.......@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/Apache/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

If I am using IE, Firefox or Safari, and type http://test.localhost/ then everything is fine.

But when try it in Chrome or Opera, it shows the `D:/Apache/htdocs/index.html`

It seems, for some reason the virtual hosts not works.

Of course, I tried to search for it on the net, and found this topic:

[Chrome localhost does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467573/chrome-localhost-does-not-work)

Tried to modified the hosts file with the IPV6 version, tried to flush the DNS, restart machine, etc... nothing helped.

Is there any more suggestion for me?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same experience with Opera browser.
I just entered HTTP protocol manually and it worked for me.

```
http://myvhost.loc
```

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment but I wanted to help :p