# Angular does not work in Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webstorm

I have created an Angular-cli project in WebStorm and when I run the project by click on Run icon I can see my project in `http://127.0.0.1:4200/` or `http://localhost:4200/` but when I copy these links into Chrome I can not see my project and it seems that the Chrome browser does not work. I see all related pages but I could not find a solution.

Comment: what's the error message? Perhaps  you need to configure your hosts file. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467573/chrome-localhost-does-not-work

Comment: So does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Probably your code has error and you have to debug by opening javascript console and looking for errors.

Answer (score 7):

Do this...

**run your app using 'ng serve'**

if the app is not opened on browser

**load the app using http://127.0.0.1:4200/**

**Enter ctrl+shift+i to open the browser console** check whether there is an error if found debug it from your app.

if it is not work try with bellow

you may install **cors plugin** from chrome web store and **active cros origin resorce sharing**  and re-try.

best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. 
After running ng serve and open web page in Chrome it displays:

```
This page isn't working.
```

In Edge the application works normally.

Even in IE 11 I get response and display but Chrome somehow ...

Added:

Ok I've managed to find a workaround for Chrome.
When using http://localhost:4200 in Chrome it won't work.
But using 127.0.0.1:4200 works,

where 127.0.0.1 is loop back address.

Added:

After some experimenting it appears to be Chrome extension problem. Because when I opened the page in incognito mode then it worked in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use your local IP address instead of local host. It worked for me ex: http://10.0.1.30:4200

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution methods above, the beginning of the `applicationUrl` can also be checked if it is **http** or **https** caused from auto conversion by the browser. Because Google Chrome might attempt to connect to HTTPs, but there is no need to enable HTTPs for IIS Express settings.